# Display forms based on user selection - ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a `<select>` box.

User must choose one option in order to proceed.

Then, `<select>` box should disappear (`select.onchange(html.(display:hidden;))`, something like this, right?!) and the `<option>` must be sent via ajax to another file or - the same.

```
<select name="var" id="var">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Next, it will perform a query (based on the previous selection) and build a combination of forms (it may be one or more) inside a div for the user to choose:

```
<div>
  <p>Some info</p>
<form>
  <inputs>
  <inputs>
  <inputs>
</form>
</div>
```

I'm not much into javascript and I'm a bit lost with the functions (`load()`, `getJSON()` etc.).

**What is the best one for this purpose?**

I'm trying `getJSON()`*, but I'm having problems with syntax, debugging and manipulating variables, requests etc.

All PHP code is working.
I just want to add smoothness, less refreshs, ease for the user, with security and performance.

*it seems that getJSON isn't appropriate for this

Answer (score 1):

You could use the onchange Javascript event:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange

```
var selectField = document.getElementById('selectField');
selectField.onchange = function()
{
    //Select Value
    var value = selectField[selectField.selectedIndex].value;
    //Hides the field
    selectField.style.display = "none";
    //Display the value
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = value;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div id="container">
 <select id="selectField" >
  <option value ="a">A</option>
  <option value ="b">B</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Online Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/acqwwbfb/2/
This is just to get you started.

Comment: Cool, Liriant, I want to hide the box to avoid the user changing from option to option, and, then, performing too many SQL queries and overloading the server. What's the best approach in this case?

Answer (score 1):

while you tagged a jquery you can use `.on('change')` and create array of forms you will need to use .. like this

in Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('select#var').on('change',function(){
    var getValue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
       url : 'yourUrl.php',
       type : 'post',
       data : {value : getvalue},
       success : function (data){
          alert(data);
          /*if(data !== 0){
             $('#show_forms').html(data);
          }*/
       },
       error : function(){
         alert('error please check the url');
       }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

index.php file you linked js with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="var" id="var">
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<div id="show_forms"></div>
```

yourUrl.php file you'll check the dabase in

```
<?php 
  echo $_POST['value'];
?>
```

after this code you should get alert with the select value

Comment: Mohamed, forms will be built based on a SQL query. If there is no returned row at all, then no form is displayed; but if one or more rows are found, then it will display as many forms as rows. That's why I want to use "ajax" instead of plain PHP (because of refreshes).

Comment: @RafaelVidal  I update my answer .. you may need to starts with it .. to at least connect js with php and return the data

Comment: The reason why I want to hide the <select> box is to avoid the user changing from option to option, and, then, performing too many SQL queries and overloading the server. What's the best approach in this case, @Mohamed-Yousef?

Comment: @RafaelVidal if you want user to select just one and refresh the page if he need to select another one you can use Liriant answer .. if you just want the user not to change the options too fast .. you can disable the select till the ajax finish and then enable it back .. to let the user choose another option

Comment: I have tried your code a few times, but didn't work... Your code looks fins, but maybe you missed something. I'll try again a few hours later.